# Создание кнопки с нуля на xlib c++

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib

Всем привет. Хочу сделать функцию, которая делает такие кнопки с помощью библиотеки xlib:

[image]

В интернете гуглил, но ничего не нашел.

Функция должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
void Button(std::string button_text, int x, int y){ ... }
```

И еще надо сделать ивенты при нажатии и т.д, но у меня вообще нет идей как это сделать, но я знаю что это реально.

Может ли кто-нибудь показать как это сделать?

Comment: Где-то в 90-х у O'Reilly была [книжка](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xlib-programming-manual/9780596806187/) (на английком), по которой я тогда программировал подбные штучки. Плопробуйте где-то найти ее pdf и ... (там было достаточно примеров)